# Is it possible to forward the output of a deep-learning network to another network with caffe / pycaffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using caffe, or more likely pycaffe to train and create my network. I am having a dataset with 5 labels at the end. I had the idea to create one network for each label that can just simply say the score for one class. After having then trained 5 networks I want to compare the outputs of the networks and which one has the highest score.

Sadly I do only know how to create one network , but not how to let them interact and moreover how to do something like a max function at the end. I add a picture to describe what I want to do.

Moreover, I do not know if this would have a better outcome than just a normal deep neuronal network[image].

Comment: Firstly you can't have a network for one-class you must have positive and negative class to start with. after you accomplish this you can apply ensemble model which is in general average on the result.

Comment: can't the network tell me sth like "I am 70% sure that this is an apple" ?

Comment: No, it can't.  All it knows is that it's seen apples.  There is no adjustment, because there's no outer boundary.  Are you confusing this with a one-class SVM?  That's a different model class.

Comment: Yes I may. So what I could do is train a network to diffferentiate between apples and dogs and then another one to differentiate between apples and cats and one between dogs and cats?

Comment: The better way to apply ensemble model. is to train the 5 networks individually with different structure or parameters on all the classes and then take the average of the result. it is noted that will higher your mdel accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what you expect to have as the input to this "max" function.  Even if you use some sort of *is / is not* boundary training, your approach appears to be an inferior version of the **softmax** layer available in all popular frameworks.

Yes, you can build a multi-channel model, train each channel with a different data set, and then accept the most confident prediction -- but the result will take longer and be less accurate than a cooperative training pass.  Your five channels wind up negotiating their boundaries *after* they've made other parametric assumptions.

Feed a single model all the information available from the outset; you'll get faster convergence and more accurate classification.

Comment: I got the problem that I do not have the same amount of data for each class (e.g 771 samples for class 5 but 28 800 samples for class 1) , so I thought that I may get to work around this problem by doing this

Comment: Don't panic over the unbalanced training examples.  Try it first to see whether you get good training.  One of the nice things about a CNN is that it's pretty good at working with such data sets.

Comment: I thought so but unluckiliy it did not. Only when simply used the same amount of data from every class I got a higher score. But due to the lack of data I now do not get much higher since the net is learning it by heart

Comment: In that case, what leads you to believe that you *can* get a higher score?  Also, what is this "higher score" metric you're using?  Classification accuracy vs some other data set?

Comment: I am using the kappa score. I think it will get better with smaller nets and so with less weights that are not able to learn it by heart.